# AWS EC2 Instance - Using User Data to ssh an existing machine is not working

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a requirement to ssh an existing machine and run some script after the newly created EC2 instance is up. I came to know it can be done with User Data field.

Below is what I am trying.

```
#!/bin/bash
service docker start
wget -P /home/ec2-user/ https://s3.amazonaws.com/(myKeyLocation)
chmod 400 /home/ec2-user/key.pem
ssh -i /home/ec2-user/key.pem ec2-user@MYEC2InstancePublicDNS nohup mkdir FileCreated
```

Below is the log output from /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start docker.service    
Host key verification failed.
```

I am not sure why "Host key verification failed" is prompting as error. If I login to the Ec2 instance and execute the same command, it works as expected.

Can anyone have an idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: The error generally occurs when it can’t find/ verify the host key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts. Is the script running as a different user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am understanding, You have two ec2 machine host1 and host2. You are trying to execute some commands on host2 by executing the above-mentioned bash script.

If you are saying that you have already tried manually and its working fine then I am unsure what exactly you are trying to do. However, I am mentioning 2 methods to remove the key from ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

Try:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

It will remove the old key.

or Just disable host key checking while logging into the machine in bootstrap script.

```
#!/bin/bash
service docker start
wget -P /home/ec2-user/ https://s3.amazonaws.com/(myKeyLocation)
chmod 400 /home/ec2-user/key.pem
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ec2-user/key.pem ec2-user@MYEC2InstancePublicDNS nohup mkdir FileCreated
```

Do let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Yes StrictHostkeyChecking flag was what I was missing. I was trying to auto scale and was trying to run it in User Data every time a new EC2 is scaled up.